# создание экземпляра класса с произвольным числом php

Tags: php

здравствуйте, мне нужно создать экземпляр класса и чтобы в конце его названия было определенное число, как это можно сделать?

то есть имеем число 2 или 3, и в зависимости от числа создать либо class2 = new Class; либо class3 = new Class;

грубо говоря

```
$int = 2;
 class.$int = new Class;
```

получаем имя экземпляра $class2;

Comment: class зарезервивано, его так использовать нельзя, можно попробовать так  `${myclass . $num}` http://ideone.com/sdIiOw

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто обернуть в `{}`.

К примеру:

```
$int = 2;
${'class' . $int} = new Class();

var_dump($class2); //Выведет объект класса.
```